# C# - How to reference my current instance of Form1 from another class in my winforms application?

Tags: c#, winforms, instance

Apologies if this doesn't make sense! Fairly new to WinForms and this is for a uni assessment. My main form is as below with the method I want to call in another class. I've renamed from Form1 to LoginPage.

```
public partial class LoginPage : Form
    {
        public LoginPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Customer.LoadCustomerDB();
        }

        public string PinText
        {
            get { return PINNumTxt.Text; }
            set { PINNumTxt.Text = value; }
        }
    }
```

My other class looks to verify the PinText which I've made accessible with the function above.

```
    class BankCard
    {
        // Attributes
        private Customer customer;
        private int pinAttempts = 0;
        private bool cardUnusable = false;

        // Member functions
        public void VerifyPIN()
        {
            LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage();
            foreach (Customer c in Customer.customers)
            {
                if (c.GetID().ToString() == loginPage.AccountNum())
                {
                    customer = c;
                }
            }

            if (cardUnusable == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("This card is currently blocked. Please contact your bank.");
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            else if (loginPage.PinText == customer.GetPIN())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Success!");
            }
            else if (pinAttempts < 2)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect PIN attempt " + (pinAttempts + 1) + "/3");
                loginPage.PinText = "";
                pinAttempts += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("3 failed PIN attempts. Please contact your bank.");
                cardUnusable = true;
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
```

My issue is that where I have the following:

```
LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage();
```

This creates a new instance of the main page, doubles up the CustomerDB being loaded in and causes errors in my VerifyPin() function.

Is the issue that I need to somehow have LoginPage loginPage = current instance of LoginPage? And if so, how would I code that?

Thanks for any help

Comment: There's no such thing as the "current" instance. There are only instances and references. You need to provide a reference for the form instance you care about.

Comment: How would I reference the default instance?

Comment: `Application.OpenForms.OfType<LoginPage>().FirstOrDefault()` is another way to find it/them/that it doesn't exist.  But perhaps you should be passing a connection to the DB to the login form rather than having it create its own.

Comment: You didn't show who creates and keeps a reference to the `BankCard` class. Presumably, if that is the Form (`LoginPage`), you could pass the reference via `this` and store the reference inside `BankCard` so that the `VerifyPin()` method can access it. Let us know if you want to see an example of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wyck's comment got it to run without any errors. I had to do:

```
LoginPage loginPage = Application.OpenForms.OfType<LoginPage>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Thanks all

Answer (score -1):

In most winforms projects, there is a `Program` class that has `Application.Run(new Form1());` (or whatever your main form is called, `LoginPage` in your case). In the `Program` class you can create a static variable `public static LoginPage loginPage;`
then in the `Main` function:

```
static void Main()
{
    loginPage = new LoginPage();
    Application.Run(loginPage);
}
```

then when you want the reference to `loginPage` in any of your classes you can just use `Program.loginPage`